# stripe params using javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe in conjunction with Parse Cloud Code.

I can pass the token ID and the customer email, but I need their name too. Stripe doesn't have any straight JS docs so it's difficult to understand. How can I pass the name?

Here's my client side code:

```
  Parse.Cloud.run('createCustomer',{
        token: token.id,
        email: token.email,
    }, {
        // Success handler
            success: function(message) {
                alert('Success: ' + message);
            },
            // Error handler
            error: function(message) {
                alert('Error: ' + message);
            }
    })
```

and the backend Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createCustomer", function(request, response) {   
console.log(request.params) 
    Stripe.Customers.create({
        account_balance: 0,
        email: request.params.email,
        description: "stripe customer",
        metadata: {

            userId: request.params.objectId, // e.g PFUser object ID
            createWithCard: true
        }

    }, {
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            response.success(name + userId); // return customerId

        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse");
            response.error("Cannot create a new customer.");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. And yes, there is little documentation on this. :)

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createCustomer", function(request, response) {    

Stripe.Customers.create({
    card: request.params.cardToken, // the token id should be sent from the client
    // account_balance: 0,
    email: request.params.email,
    description: 'new stripe user',
    metadata: {
        name: request.params.name
    }
}, 
{
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        response.success(httpResponse); // return customerId
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log(httpResponse);
        response.error(httpResponse);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Can we create a customer with parse objectİd of the user. If I set the userId the meta info is not very useful for the query. stripe customers retrieve needs the customerid